# Which policy hides all desktop items?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, group-policy, domain

New accounts on my Windows Server 2012 look like this when logging in for the first time:

[image]

As you can see, the desktop is empty. It is not, there are in fact files on the desktop, but they are not shown here. Somebody enabled a policy that hides everything from the desktop, while there are in fact items (this is the Desktop folder in Explorer):

[image]

Which policy is this so I can disable it? I can confirm it is not `User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Desktop\Hide and disable all items on the desktop`.

Comment: Can you check the value of registry key "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\HideIcons"

Comment: @ngn Nothing special I think. http://i.imgur.com/b59s7ZL.png

Comment: Is the "User Experience" feature installed? http://serverfault.com/questions/646935/how-can-i-hide-the-recycle-bin-on-windows-server-2012

Comment: @Craig620 Nope.